# Formato a excel usando maatwebsite/excel 3.1 Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-7, maatwebsite

estoy usando la libreria maatwebsite/excel 3.1 de Laravel para descargar excel.  Hasta el momento he logrado que el excel me descargue con sus datos correspondientes, pero mi problema es que debo darle una estructura al excel, por ejemplo empezar en la línea 10 y no en la 1, darle color a ciertas columnas.  Tengo un controlador Export y otro controlador llamado Detalles.

En mi Export tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php
namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;

class Export implements FromArray
{
    protected $data;

    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function array(): array
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

En mi controlador de detalle, tengo la siguiente function

```
public function descargar($st, Request $request){
        $file="Archivo";
        $data=array(
            array("", "num","","id","","idt","estado","fecha","numero","","letra","identificador","area","desc","nombre")
        );

        $sociedades=Sociedad::where('ar', '=', $st)->get();

        foreach ($sociedades as $row){
       $vacio = "";
           array_push($data, array(
                $vacio,
                $row->num,
                $vacio,
                $row->id,
                $vacio,
                $row->idt,
                $row->ap_materno,
                $row->estado,
                $row->fecha,
                $row->numero,
                $vacio,
                $row->letra,
                $row->identificador,
                $row->area,
                $row->desc,
                $row->nombre
            ));
        }

        $export = new Export($data);
        return Excel::download($export, $file.'.xlsx');
    }
```

Como dije el excel me descarga la información pero necesito llegar del ejemplo A al B, para explicarme mejor a donde quiero llegar, ver imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probaste agregar al array líneas vacías al inicio? Por ej: `$data=array( array("", "","","","","","","","","","","","","",""), array("", "num","","id","","idt","estado","fecha","numero","","letra","identificador","area","desc","nombre") );`

Comment: Si amigo, ya lo logre! ahora estoy en los colores